# Asp.Net Core - add custom configuration file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to add a custom configuration file so I can keep clean the appsettings.json file and use it only for keys. I use the Options pattern to bind the configurations to an object. Now, the problem is when I inject the options in a controller constructor, I get null values like the configurations are not loaded.

Here are the changes I made:

**Program.cs**

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

             // Here I attach the additional configuration file
             .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
             {
                 config.AddJsonFile("wwwroot\\Configurations\\EventTypes.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
             })
             .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.Configure<EventTypes>(configuration.GetSection("Types"));
```

**EventTypes.json**

```
{
  "Types": [
    {
      "Id": "8",
      "Type": "Marathon"
    },
    {
      "Id": "9",
      "Type": "FlashMob"
    },
    {
      "Id": "10",
      "Type": "Other"
    }
  ]
}
```

the options class
**EventTypes.cs**

```
public class EventTypes
    {
        public EventTypes()
        {

        }
        public List<EventConfiguration> Types { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventConfiguration
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
private readonly EventTypes eventTypes;

        // c-tor
        public PostController(IOptions<EventTypes> eventTypes)
        {
            // When I debug, eventTypes.Types is null
            this.eventTypes = eventTypes.Value;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure `wwwroot\\Configurations\\EventTypes.json` is accessible from your current directory? I mean, `File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "wwwroot\\Configurations\\EventTypes.json"))` is `true`?

Comment: and also are you sure if `EventTypes.json` is copied to the output dir, in that relative path?

Comment: @dcg yes, otherwise it was throwing errorr that it couldn't find the file

Comment: You might be missing 1 level of properties. `configuration.GetSection("Types")` will return anything in the `Types` block, which is your array. For fun, could you try adding another `Types` object to contain your `Types` array? `{ "Types" :  { "Types" : [...]}}`

Comment: @ESG Yeah you are right :) such a stupid mistake